# ¿Es posible consumir una clase en net5 dentro de un webservice hecho en .net framework 4.7.2?

Tags: c#

Buen dia,

Estoy tratando de hacer un webservice para consumir un libreria hecha en netcore 5. La libreria utiliza un wrapper uplink.net para usar la plataforma storj y en una consola funciona correctamente pero si la hago libreria y quiero consumirla dentro de un webservice con framework 4.7.2 no logro ver la libreria.

Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo que no se puede.

Answer (score 0):

No. Solo [.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) es compatible entre ambos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]